# POSTFIX and allowing a domain to send emails via another domain

Tags: postfix

We are using POSTFIX mail server and if we send mail from our main domain then gmail does not thread mail as spam, but if we send it from second domain then is threaded as spam. What can we do?

How to configure postfix that we allowing a domain to send emails via another domain and gmail will not recognize it as spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at [SPF](http://www.openspf.org/) records.

Possibly something like this:

`"v=spf1 a:anotherdomain.tld -all"`

Then you need to make sure there is a proper A record for the mail server under the second domain.

Comment: Thx and what if A record in second domain is not set to first domain?

Comment: OK, basically, on your first domain you have an A record saying mail.firstdomain.com = 1.2.3.4, you will need another record in the second domain saying mail.seconddomain.com = 1.2.3.4 also. Then when you publish the SPF record, they will look for an A record in seconddomain.com, and if the IP address of the server is there, it will pass.

Comment: You need to publish it in your DNS, the site I linked to in my post should explain most everything you know.

Comment: Not a problem, make sure to read up a bit on what I've recommended!

Comment: i am already reading